# Javascript src from file depending on domain name

Tags: php, javascript, iframe

I have file http://host1.com/links.txt

links.txt contain:

```
com http://host1.com/1.jpg
info http://host1.com/2.jpg
org http://host1.com/3.jpg
```

I need to put in this code src link from that file depending on host domain.

```
a=document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
st='iframe';
r=st;
b=document.createElement(r);
b.src=**Here from links.txt**
b.width=300;b.height=300;b.marginHeight=10;b.marginWidth=10;b.frameborder=10;b.align='left';
a.appendChild(b);
```

for example I have 3 other sites

```
1. http://site1.com
2. http://site2.info
3. http://site3.org
```

In each site index.php I need put that iframe code, and in source code of:

http://site1.com/index.php
I must have b.src=http://host1.com/1.jpg

http://site1.info/index.php
I must have b.src=http://host1.com/2.jpg

http://site1.org/index.php
I must have b.src=http://host1.com/3.jpg

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have control over the `links.txt` and can change it to JSON, you can use [JSONP](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) to read it.

You can get the hostname by using `window.location.hostname`.

**links.php**

```
<?php header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8'); ?>

(function(){
    var data = {
        com: 'http://host1.com/1.jpg',
        info: 'http://host1.com/2.jpg',
        org: 'http://host1.com/3.jpg'
    };

    <?php echo $_GET['callback']; ?>(data);
})();
```

**javascript**

```
$(function(){
    $.ajax({
       type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://mysite.com/links.php?callback=?',
        async: false,
        jsonpCallback: 'jsonpCallback',
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(json) {
           alert(json.info);
           alert(json.com);
           alert(json.org);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I only can use javascript or PHP

Comment: JSONP/jQuery *is* javascript

Comment: I've updated my example to give a better idea of how it works.